# PHP SOAP client with certificates over SSL

Tags: php, ssl, soap, wsdl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to set up a Soap client with the following code:

```
<?php
$wsdl           = 'https://domain.com/?wsdl';
$endpoint       = 'https://domain.com';
$certificate    = dirname(__FILE__) . '/CertWithKey.pem';
$password       = 'pwd';

$options = array(
    'location'      => $endpoint,
    'keep_alive'    => true,
    'trace'         => true,
    'local_cert'    => $certificate,
    'passphrase'    => $password,
    'cache_wsdl'    => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
);

try {
    $soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

I was given a .p12 key-file with a .crt certification file. Using openssl I've converted the .p12-file to a .pem-file and then merged it with the .crt-file. The CertWithKey.pem looks good to me, two certificate-blocks are in the file.

No matter what I try to do, I keep getting an exception with the message `SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://domain.com/?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://domain.com/?wsdl"`.

After phoning with the remote party they acknowlegde that a request is coming in but they're logging this error: `ssl handshake interrupted by system [hint: stop button pressed in browser?!]`.

Since I didn't find any useful information on the net so far I figured to ask you guys for some insight on the matter.

Any suggestions what can be tried? I'm running PHP 5.3.8 and the server's IP-address is white listed in the firewall at the remote party.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've fixed this problem. I think, due to the number of questions regarding this issue and number of different solutions, others will benefit from the solution. Here goes:

I used the `openssl` CLI program to convert the .p12 key-file to a .pem key-file. The trick is the way the conversion takes place.

First I converted it with this command and I had the issue as described in the question:

`openssl pkcs12 -in key.p12 -out key.pem -nodes -clcerts`

While the command below did the actual trick:

`openssl pkcs12 -in key.p12 -out key.pem -clcerts`

For more info please see the source I used: https://community.qualys.com/docs/DOC-3273

Comment: I am also trying to send SOAP request to a server. 
I am facing a similar issue where I am not able to communicate to the server through my php application. but works through SOAP GUI.
I have a .p12 file which I have tried to use by converting to .pem file.

When I create the SOAP client object, I get the error: 
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from https://<serverurl>?wsdl  : failed to load external entity https://<serverurl>?wsdl
Can you please tell me what is going wrong here?

Comment: If you have followed my answer and the key and crt files are merged succesfully the remote host might have a firewall enabled and is blocking your IP-adress. Otherwise I can't tell yet, maybe you should open a question then.

Comment: I had the same issue. And I followed exact steps that @Ben has provided. The p12 had to be converted into .pem  using the link provided.But I was still getting the error:
 curl: (58) Unable to load client cert -8018
Strangely, I figured our that the passphrase that I was providing was 3-digits '123', instead I had to provide some valid passphrase of 6 alphabetic characters.
So I believe, there should be a some good length passphrase (Dont know the min length).The next this that was missing was 'local_cert', 'passphrase' options that should be supplied in the SoapClient object initialization.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $mode = array(
            'soap_version' => 'SOAP_SSL_METHOD_SSLv2',  // use soap 1.2 client
            'trace' => 1,
            'stream_context' => stream_context_create(
            array(
                'ssl' => array(
                    'crypto_method' =>  STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT,
                    'verify_peer' => false,  // don't care about which company
                    'verify_peer_name' => false  // or company name
                    )   
                )
            )
        );

        $client = new SoapClient($x, $mode);
```

Answer (score -1):

Same suggestions:

1. I use SoapClient to connect with SSL services, and all works fine without specify "endpoint" URL. Then I recommend you try without this option;
2. The php SoapClient has a option named "ssl_method" where you can change some variation of this protocol. Try change/specify this param if you know what protocol is used;
3. Specify "verifypeer => false" and "verifyhost => false" on params list;

Comment: Thanks for your reply. `1:` I've tried it as well without the endpoint; with no luck. `2:` Due to my PHP version I'm unable to use ssl_method. `3:` Am I wrong or are verifypeer and verifyhost undocumented parameters (or at least they're not in the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php). No difference in supplying them either.

Comment: `Specify "verifypeer => false" and "verifyhost => false" on params list;` This means disable security. always a bad idea

Comment: If you look at the c source code for the soap extension for php you'll see that neither verifyhost not verifypeer are supported, so suggestion #3 here should be ignored.

Comment: This answer worked for me, with a little extra research.  Those options mentioned are set in the ssl options inside the stream_context option.