# PHP : How to add keystore for SOAP https request

Tags: php, web-services, soap, https, wsdl

I am  new in PHP .One of my PHP projects requires making a SOAP call to access a web service over HTTPS.

the service provider only gave us three file .jks, .p12. and .wsdl file.I tested the .wsdl file in SOAPUI tool it's working.I uploaded my .jks file in SOAPUI *preference >ssl settings*

then I wrote my PHP code

```
<?php



$wsdl = 'http://localhost/RbphpGateway/librb/RB_OLP_INITIATE_PAYMENT.wsdl';


try{
    $clinet=new SoapClient($wsdl);

    $ver =array("olpIdAlias"=>"****","merchantId"=>"***","merchantRefNum"=>"418934223","paymentAmount"=>"100","paymentCurrency"=>"USD","dynamicMerchantLandingURL"=>"","dynamicMerchantFailureURL"=>"");
    $quates=$clinet->executeRB_OLP_INITIATE_PAYMENT($ver);

    echo  $quates->initiatePaymentDetailsRes->ibURL;


}catch(SoapFault $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

**my Output is**

> Could not connect to host

as my knowledge for secure https connection,  we need to add a keystore with the code.
can anybody give me hint how to add a certificate in PHP.? can i add my .jks file with php .?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found solution . first i generated .pem file using [openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27062639/php-soap-client-with-certificates-over-ssl)  from .p12

```
$wsdl = dirname(__FILE__).'/librb/xxxxxx.wsdl';

$endpoint       = 'https://pay.bnk.com/soap?service=payment';
$local_cert = dirname(__FILE__)."/key1.pem";
$passphrase = "*****";
$options = array(

    'location'      => $endpoint,
    'keep_alive'    => true,
    'trace'         => true,
    'local_cert'    => $local_cert,
    'passphrase'    => $passphrase,
    'cache_wsdl'    => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
'trace'       => 1,     // traces let us look at the actual SOAP messages later
        'exceptions'  => 1 ,

);

try{
   $client = new SoapClient($wsdl,$options)
    } catch (SoapFault $E) { 
        echo $E->getMessage();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that the problem has something to do with https, especially when you describe that it works in SoupUI.

Which host is it that you can not connect to?
You refer to the wsdl file on localhost, and I suspect that the web service is located on a different host?
So is the probleme linked to localhost or to the ws-host?

Start ensuring that you have access to then wsdl-file and by adding options trace = 1 and exception = 0 when creating the `$clinet` :

```
$clinet=new SoapClient($wsdl,array('trace' => 1, 'exception' => 0));
```

It allows you to examine the soap result further by using `$client->__getLastRequest()`

Comment: do you know how to use .jks(keystore) file in php code.in Soapui i upload .jks in preference > ssl settings

Comment: No, I don't know anything about .jks. But how did you manage to connect via SoapUI? Did you setup any security settings in the project-profile, so SoapUI is sending security headers in addition to the ordinary communication?

Comment: I add my WSDL to SOAPUI tool . then create a test case. then upload my .jks(keystore format) file into my soapui preference > SSL settings and set password . this is what i did in soapui .

Comment: Try analysing the traffic in SoapUI using the "http log" (Located in the bottom panel). In particular look for Header-ithems. When using Soap in PHP, you have to set the header just like that, before doing the main call