# How to connect external server through pem file and PHP

Tags: php, wsdl, pem, jks

Am having .jks file and I want to connect one of bank server from my website by using this jks file.

First I converted this .jks file to pkcs by using this command

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore client.jks -destkeystore client.pkcs -srcstoretype JKS -deststoretype PKCS12
```

Then convert pkcs to pem file by using this command `openssl pkcs12 -in client.pkcs -out client.pem`

Then I use this PHP code to connect

```
<?php 

    try{
    $url = "https://b2brbtest.riyadbank.com/soap?service=RB_OLP_INITIATE_PAYMENT";
     $certFile =  dirname(__FILE__)."/client.pem";
      $certPass = "xxxxx";
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 443);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $certFile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, $certPass);

    $headers = array();
    array_push($headers, "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    array_push($headers, "SOAPAction: sii:RB_OLP_INITIATE_PAYMENT");
    array_push($headers, "Host:b2brbtest.riyadbank.com");

    if($xml != null) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
        array_push($headers, "Content-Length: " . strlen($xml));
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  
    print curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

         print_r($response);
    }  catch (Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    ?>
```

It returning this error 
**OUTPUT**

> Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to b2brbtest.riyadbank.com:443

am using wireshark to track the network.

am trying this same PHP code from my localhost, its reach the destination IP and showing this error 
**OUTPUT**

> 'Failed to connect to b2brbtest.riyadbank.com port 443: Timed out'.

But when I try this same code from my website am getting this error 
**OUTPUT**

> 'SSL protocol error in connection to b2brbtest.riyadbank.com:443 '.

I dont know what is my mistake. anyone please help me to fix this.

I got reference from here [PHP : Curl https xml result returns blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39616026/php-curl-https-xml-result-returns-blank) but not working