# Connection to web service with Soapclient

Tags: php, web-services, ssl, soap-client

I am trying connect to web service with local cert in php. Soapclient return this error: `Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient(): Unable to set local cert chain file ***.p12'; Check that your cafile/capath settings include details of your certificate and its issuer in url on line 226`. This cert hasn't cafile... What can i do? My code is this:

```
$wsdl       = 'url';

try {
    $soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(
        "trace"         => 1, 
        "exceptions"    => false, 
        "endpoint"      => $wsdl,
        "soap_version"  => SOAP_1_1 ,
        "location"      => "url",
        'stream_context' => stream_context_create(array(
            'ssl' => array(
                "verify_peer" => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => false,
                'ciphers' => 'DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:AES256-SHA',
                'crypto_method' =>  STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT,
                "local_cert"    => '***.p12',
                "passphrase"    => ******,
            )
        )) 
    )
);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($soapClient);
    echo "</pre>";
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($e);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

In Java, it is necessary use truststore but i don`t know to do equivalent in php.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check this one ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/27105158/2629508

Comment: Yes, WS return this error: `failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 No Encontrado in url`. I don't know if this error is because i need send xml or because WS don't accept cert...

Comment: If i change verify_peer and verify_peer_name to true, WS return this error: `SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed`